# Mixing C and C++ code with userdefined "typename()" function in C

Tags: c++, c, mixing

I am trying to write a C++ code where I call a C function, lets say `hello_world()`
which in-turn calls a user-defined `typename()` function. When I include my C code in C++, there is a compilation error, I know that `typename` is a keyword in C++ but then to include C code, I'm using

```
extern "C" { #include "hello_world.h"}
```

in my C++ code, and still there is an error during compilation, any suggestions to avoid this and to compile the code, i would be grateful.

I cannot change the name of user defined `typename()` function to other name. so how to go about...?

The errors as such :
`In file included from New_test.cpp:19:0:
    ../tools/symbol.h:38:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘typename’
    ../tools/symbol.h:38:14: error: expected initializer before ‘typename’
    In file included from New_test.cpp:604:0:
    /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/poll.h: In function ‘int readpacket(channel*, void*, size_t)’:
    /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/poll.h:48:1: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
    New_test.cpp:612:52: error: ‘poll’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: In all likelihood, you can partition your headers such that `typename()` gets declared only in the C source from which it's invoked.  Minimize the headers included by the C++ source.  If you need to be able to invoke `typename()` from C++, consider changing your design to accept a function pointer.

Comment: How can i restrict typename() to be declared only in C source. does using "extern "C" { #include "some_c.h"}" doesn't do it...?

Comment: the c only... but i call a C function which calls typename()...

Comment: Trilok, please share more info -- the bounty description makes it sound as if one or more of the answers are adequate but you want more evidence "drawing from credible and/or official sources."  As the question is currently described, I think my answer is sufficient.  If you have an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) it would help.

Comment: @TrilokM, please specify what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 7):

You probably need something like this in your header file:

File: common_header.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void newname_typename();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and then a C-only compile unit:

```cpp
#include "common_header.h"
#include "hello_world.h"
void newname_typename() {
   typename();
}
```

and in C++:

```cpp
#include "common_header.h"

void do_stuff() {
  newname_typename();
}
```

and you need to ensure your Makefile ends up doing the following:

```
gcc c_only_code.c -o something1.o
g++ cplus_only_code.cxx -o something2.o
gcc something1.o something2.o <other stuff> -o binary
```

Comment: should i use gcc cplus_only_code.c -o something2.o or g++ cplus_only_code.cpp -o something2.o...?

Comment: and whats the use of -o binary...? is it compulsory...?

Comment: sorry, fixed my typo.  But that was just an example, it depends on your build system.  Also (binary) was just an example for the executable.  I was just trying to emphasise that you need to ensure the C code gets compiler by a C compiler and the C++ with a C++ compiler

Comment: In order to use "extern "C"{ #include "some.h" }" do i need to create a shared library of some.h  ?

Comment: Because i tried use extern "C" { #include "some.h"} where my some.h has all the c functions defined and my cpp code is still non-compilable

Comment: your some.h C must be compatible with C++. There is no workaround, extern C doesnt help, it only permits C linkage. You must modify some.h or create a new compatible header file (common_header.h) as described above.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can partition things such that it should compile and link correctly.  The C++ source file does not need to know that there's a function called `typename()`.

File '`some_c.c`':

```
#include "some_c.h"

void typename(); /* This declaration will suffice. */

void hello_world()
{
    typename();
}
```

---

File '`some_c.h`'

```
/* References to typename()'s declaration must be deleted from this
** header file.  If it turns out that there are some other parts of the
** header file which somehow depend on the typename() declaration, you
** must separate this into multiple header files. 
*/
void hello_world();
```

---

File '`some_cpp.cpp`':

```
/* Arguably this should show up in some_c.h, protected by
** #ifdef __cplusplus barriers.  But this should work too:
*/
extern "C" {
#include "some_c.h"
}

void SomeClass::someMethod()
{
    hello_world();
}
```

Comment: /* References to typename()'s declaration must be deleted from this
** header file.  If it turns out that there are some other parts of the
** header file which somehow depend on the typename() declaration, you
** must separate this into multiple header files. 
*/
so where exactly i should declare typename();

Comment: You must declare `typename()` in `some_c.c` or somewhere else not included by `some_cpp.cpp`.

Comment: In order to use "extern "C"{ #include "some.h" }" do i need to create a shared library of some.h  ?

Comment: Because i tried use extern "C" { #include "some.h"} where my some.h has all the c functions defined and my cpp code is still non-compilable.

Comment: No, you do not need a library, shared or otherwise.  "still no-compilable" -- ok, why does it fail?

Answer (score 3):

extern "C" doesn't tell the c++ compiler to compile in C, but it tells to use C type linkage. 
Code incompatible with C++ will still generate errors. You must use the "bad" C header files only in C code. Create a new C header file which expose the required functions/code (compatible with C++ through wrapping/renaming) and use that new file C Header in the C++ code and with extern "C".

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that there is an official answer to this question.  The reason is that the `extern "C"` directive has an official usage and intent, and all of the authoritative documentation will discuss that usage and intent.  You are trying to use `extern "C"` for something it wasn't intended for. An official document that discusses all unintended use cases would be hard to find. I submit that such a document would be infinitely long.

The intent of `extern "C"` is to allow C functions to call C++ functions and vice versa.  The issue arises because by default C++ uses a different naming convention in object files than C does.  C++ uses mangled function names, C uses straight forward function names.  Also C++ may pass variables to a function differently than C.  To allow C++ to call C functions (and vice versa), the `extern "C"` informs the compiler that it needs to use the C function calling conventions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extern_%22C%22#Linking_C_and_C.2B.2B_code

Therefore given the following requirements

```
1) a function named `typename` exists in a C source file
2) the function cannot be renamed
3) the function must be callable from a C++ source file
```

the only solution is to create a bridge file as fully explained in the post by Andrew McDonnell.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone with the same problem : In order to invoke a C function with function name being same as a defined keyword in C++ is to use extern "C" { /*function declaration */} and also you need to have a Shared Library.

Thank you all...!!!